# PHP dynamic zip file creation crashes with non-image filetypes. (wp)

Tags: php, wordpress, zip

I have a function that takes uploaded files (WORDPRESS) and adds them to a (newly created) zip file.
every new file is added to the zip (if is not yet created - the first file will create one ) and also to a comment with the list of the files.

```
 function Ob99_generate_zip_file($meta) {
     // we always need post_id , right ?
    if( isset($_GET['post_id']) ) {
            $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        } elseif( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
            $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        }
        //setting some more variables.
        $file =  wp_upload_dir();// take array
        $file2 = wp_upload_dir();//debug
        $zipname = $file['path'].'file.zip'; // set zip file name
        $file = trailingslashit($file['basedir']).$meta['file'];// construct real path

            // Without this next condition the function dies. WHY ??
        list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file); // not help to comment
        if (!$orig_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || !$orig_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG|| !$orig_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { 
         //why other filetypes not working ??
         return ;
        }

    $zip = new ZipArchive; // initiatte class
    $zip->open($zipname , ZipArchive::CREATE); // open buffer
    $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1); //we do not need nested folders
    $zip->addFile($file,$sitename.'/'.$new_filename); // we add the file to the zip
    if (file_exists($zipname)){
    $comment = $zip->getArchiveComment();  // if the file already exist read the comment
    } 
    else { // if not - let´s give it a cool retro header
    $comment_head = '*********************************'. PHP_EOL ;
    $comment_head .= '****** <<< FILE CONTENT >>> *****'. PHP_EOL ;
    $comment_head .= '*********************************'. PHP_EOL ;

    }
    $comment = $comment_head . $comment ;// add header before comment
    $comment = $comment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $meta['file'] ; // add new file name
    $zip->setArchiveComment($comment); // and comment
    $zip->addFromString('filelist.txt', $comment); // create txt file with the same list
    $zip->close()or die('can not create zip file'.$file.print_r($meta).'---- DEBUG SEPERATOR ---- '.print_r($file2));  // FINISHED or DIE with debug
    }
```

My problem : if I try to upload any file other than an image - the function will DIE .
I have added a condition for checking imagetype - but  I would like to know why it is crashing and how to make it work without said condition ...
Does the zip function have any problems with PDF , doc or anyother ? is that a wordpress problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem section seems to be where you're asking PDFs, etc. their image size.  Why don't you try:

```
$image_size = getimagesize($file);

if($image_size===false)
{
   // This is not an image
   // Do what you want to PDFs, etc.
}
else
{
   // This is an image
   // Find out image type, dimensions, etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks - I have corrected the question post - but anyhow - the comments were made only for this post on SE . they are not in the original code .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it - but Ithink you misunderstood the problem (maybe I did not comment the code enough) . the part where I get imagesize was only added in order to filter non image files. like i wrote in the code comments .  i do not need the image size nor the mimetype - but if I do not do that if condition - it will die when loading PDF all the same. I do this condition in order not to break the whole system if someone loads PDF (and just ignore it ). but it is not what i really want .

Comment: Why do you even need to filter non-image files? If you want to zip _all_ uploaded files, why are you adding this condition?

Comment: because if i do not have this condition - the function DIE. That is the whole point of my question - why does it die if this condition is removed and the non-image files get pass...

Comment: Can you get rid of the `or die()` and see if it produces an error message? It should show you where it's going wrong.

Comment: this will produce no errors - but will not add the files as well. It is just like it is ignoring them. the upload is fine - but they will not go into the zip (this is also why i had the DIE - for debug)